# Opening a file without clicking through folder structure in Eclipse Remote System Explorer (RSE)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rse

I want to edit a file (e.g. `/root/get-pip.py`) in Eclipse Remote System Explorer (RSE). Is it possible to open it without having to  click through folder structure but instead simply typing or pasting the filepath somewhere?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-it-possible-to-open-it-without-having-to-click-through-folder-structure-but-instead-simply-typing-or-pasting-the-filepath-somewhere-in-Eclipse-RSE